# Does Master of the Veil work on Megamorphs?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-face-down-cards

Assuming I have [Master of the Veil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMaster%20of%20the%20Veil%5d) face down and [Stratus Dancer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStratus%20Dancer%5d) face up, can I flip Stratus Dancer back over with Master of the Veil? I do not know of Megamorph falls under Morph. Are they completely different, or is Megamorph and instance of Morph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Master of the Veil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMaster%20of%20the%20Veil%5d) is able to turn [Stratus Dancer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStratus%20Dancer%5d) facedown.

Rule **702.36b** defines Megamorph as a morph variant, and so [Master of the Veil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMaster%20of%20the%20Veil%5d)'s oracle'd ability can target a face up [Stratus Dancer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStratus%20Dancer%5d).

---

**Oracle text**:

> When Master of the Veil is turned face up, you may turn target creature with a morph ability face down.

**702.36. Morph**:

> **702.36a** Morph is a static ability that functions in any zone from which you could play the card it’s on, and the morph effect works any time the card is face down. “Morph [cost]” means “You may cast this card as a 2/2 face-down creature with no text, no name, no subtypes, and no mana cost by paying {3} rather than paying its mana cost.” (See rule 707, “Face-Down Spells and Permanents.”)
>   **702.36b** Megamorph is a variant of the morph ability. “Megamorph [cost]” means “You may cast this card as a 2/2 face-down creature with no text, no name, no subtypes, and no mana cost by paying {3} rather than paying its mana cost” and “As this permanent is turned face up, put a +1/+1 counter on it if its megamorph cost was paid to turn it face up.” A megamorph cost is a morph cost.

Comment: Alright, I did not know if Megamorph fell under the Morph umbrella or not.

Comment: @ShadowZ. Even without looking through the comprehensive rules, your Gatherer link for the Dancer says "Megamorph is a variant of the morph ability. You can find more information on morph on cards with morph from the Khans of Tarkir set."

Comment: @arthur I did not read too much on Stratus Dancer as it was just meant to be an example of Megamorph, and I instead focused on reading about the Master of the Veil instead, checking it's gatherer page more. My bad, it was a mistake/oversight on my part.